# What is the 7z or zip equivalent of "tar cf resulting.tar -C dir1/dir2 dir-to-zip"?

Tags: zip, tar, 7zip

Basically do either zip or 7za, 7z have a -C type option?

I know usually you would just cd to the directory but that's not an option here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an equivalent, but if you provide more details on what you're trying to do, people may be able to suggest alternative approaches.

Comment: I know of multiple other ways to do it. This question isn't so much of solving a specific problem but rather that I read the man pages and can't believe there isn't an equiv. I was just hoping someone would answer in the affirmative for future reference.